# Text input inside table cell, all using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a table full of cells that all have text input fields inside of them, using only JS.  I'm having trouble getting the inputs to populate all of the fields, and to register as text inputs rather than just inputs.  Here's the relevant code:

```
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow();
    if ((i % 3) == 0) {
        tr.setAttribute('class', 'heavy_bottom');
    }
    for (j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
        td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(text);
        if ((j % 3) == 0) {
            td.setAttribute('class', 'heavy_right');
        }
    }
}
for(var h = 0; h < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[h].type.toLowerCase() == 'submit') {
        inputs[h].parentNode.removeChild(inputs[h]); 
    } else {
        inputs[h].setAttribute('type', 'text');
    }
```

Comment: It will be much easier to reproduce the issue If you can add the HTML and CSS code too.

Comment: docs: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) should get you going in the right direction

Comment: Inputs are heavy, would just style table cells like input and append input dynamically onclick, then remove after focus lost.